# How to execute a shell command in the current cmd.exe context?

Tags: c#, .net, shell, path, cmd

So, I have a .Net utility. I need to use a utility(ilasm and ildasm) that is *sometimes* in the PATH variable and sometimes not. Specific times when it's in the path includes when using the Visual Studio command line script.. and when it's not is when you just launch a regular `cmd.exe` instance.

All of the information I've seen for executing a shell command from .Net imply that you can just create a new instance of cmd.exe, but in this case, the PATH variable will be different. The other possible thing is manually parsing the PATH variable and execute it directly with a `ProcessStartInfo` when found, but this seems error prone and unnecessary

Is there a tool or anything that would help me with this situation? How should I go about executing these utilities?

Comment: Check out if your regular environment have some `VS*` variable (just type `set VS` in command prompt) - you may be able to use them to locate tools instead of path... Or simply alter system (or user) PATH to include VS path if it is just for you.

Comment: Why are launching `cmd.exe`? Why not the program you are trying to call (if that is what you are doing)?

Comment: How can it be **sometimes**? Arr you alternating between `VS command prompt` and regular `cmd`?

Comment: @Nayan, as clarification, and correct me if I am wrong, but he is making a program that is launched from either the `VS cmd` or `regular cmd`. This switch will change the `path` variable of his program, so when he runs processes, that will be affected. Though I am still confused on exactly what he is asking and his workflow.

Comment: @gunr2171 That's why I asked him.

Comment: @gunr2171 basically, I want to execute ilasm and ildasm (which aren't included by default in system PATH, but are in the Visual Studio scriptS) from my .Net utility WITHOUT hardcoding the path or searching registry or some other ridiculous method. I'm fine with an error message when executing from the regular command line (when PATH doesn't have ilasm/ildasm), but when executing from the Visual Studio command line, it is in the PATH and I want to be able to take advantage of that

Comment: I'm not sure where I got "where" utility (or part of what OS it is), but if you have it you can check location of a tool with `where ildasm` and than check `errorlevel` in your CMD script like `where ildasm & echo %errorlevel%`...

Answer (score 0):

When you start cmd.exe, you can set its environment path:

```
 var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
 psi.EnvironmentVariables["path"] = "mypath";
 Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: why the lack of example, the lack of clarity, the lack of an answer?